# Payment completed "return to merchant" using cancel url

Tags: paypal

I'm having a weird issue with PayPal Express Checkout.

When a user completes a payment on PayPal it'll show them that the payment has been completed along with a "return to merchant" button. The button is set to the cancel URL instead of the return URL.

I'm setting the return and cancel url manually in the code when making the initial request to PayPal.

One way to reproduce this is to click back after you get automatically redirected back to the merchant's website.

Is this a bug?

[image: PayPal return url]

Comment: As of today, I'm noticing this exact problem. Did you notice it in the sandbox only or in production as well?

Comment: It was happening in production as well

Answer (score 0):

At our end, We could see that the buyer has been redirected to return URL correctly. Kindly file an MTS ticket at https://www.paypal-techsupport.com with more information for investigating this issue further.